# get parent thread Id in case of nested pthread_created

Tags: linux, pthreads

In my C code implementation, I create nested pthreads.

For example:

The application creates threads A, B, and C. Then the threads A creates A0, A1, A2; thread B creates B0, B1 and thread C creates C0, C1, C2, C3.

Now I want to know if it is possible that while executing thread C0, its parent thread Id is that of thread C. or while executing thread A2, its parent thread Id is that of thread A ?

If yes, then what is the possible API for that?

Just on a sidenote, I don't want to use arguments to be passed to the threads for some legacy reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "*parent thread Id*".

The PThread specification does not describe a parent<->child relationship between threads. So there are no PThread API calls to pull this information from somewhere.

The pthread-identifier as returned by `pthread_self()` can be used to destinguish one existing thread from all other **existing** threads of one process.

Be aware that pthread-identifiers might be recycled during the life-time of a process.

So lets say there are two threads A and B, each having its own different pthread-id ID1 and ID2. If thread A ends and after A ended B creates a new thread C this might very well have ID1 assigned as its pthread-id.

Comment: Regarding the point that you mentioned here, "Be aware that pthread-identifiers might be recycled during the life-time of a process." Can the pthread-identifiers recycling happen in between a certain execution process? Say in a thread, function a() calls b(), b() calls c() and so on... so can the pthread-identifiers be obtained different in a(), b() and c() due to this recycling?

Comment: @ankitjain: Not sure if I completely understood your question. But a PThread's identifier does not change during a PThread's lifetime.

Comment: Ok thanks, just needed to clear that. Also, is there no workaround either to get the parent thread information from current thread?

Comment: @ankitjain: At least POSIX (as well as C11 threads) do not specify such thingy. From the thread's perspective there is not such thing as a "parent" thread. If your application design defines a thread to be "a parent" the application needs to be able to identify it.

Comment: @ankitjain: People tend to call the 1st thread being created (the one which runs `main()` the "main"-thread, which could be taken a being as "parent". But still, from the POSIX/C11 implementation's perspective there is no thread-hierarchy. All threads are run on the same "level".

Comment: Right, I needed to access the parent(or you can say initializing) thread for an existing thread. So I can conclude that it is not possible for POSIX and C11 threads. Thanks.

Comment: @ankitjain Thread's are not "called". They are created, which would not mean it will run. A thread creating another thread has no influence on the created thread's run-time behaviour. Do not confused yourself using inaccurate wording.